# How can i save a list of object in sqlite in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have two classes (Reminder and Tasks) and the Reminder class contains a list of Task class which i want to save to sqlite at the same time when i am saving the reminder so some List of task can contain identical ReminderId so they can be retrieved alongside a Reminder object. In other words, I am trying to save List of Tasks and have them attached to a reminderId so they can be retrieved as a property of Reminder Class. However, when i save this information, every other property are saved except the list of Tasks which returns null when i am trying to read from db.

I have read the sqlite-extension docs and didnt find it helpful enough. I have also tried and looked for other answers on here but they didnt come out clear enough or they are not exactly what i need.

This is my Reminder Class:

```
  public class Reminder
    {
        [PrimaryKey] [AutoIncrement]
        public int ReminderId { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public string ReminderLocation { get; set; }
        //in terms of days
        public DateTime ReminderCreationDate { get; set; }

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public List<Tasks> ThingsTodo { get; set; }
```

This is my Tasks Class:

```
 public class Tasks
    {
        [AutoIncrement]
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public string Events { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Reminder))]
        public int ReminderId { get; set; }

        [ManyToOne]
        public Reminder Reminders { get; set; }

    }
```

This is how i am saving the reminder object in db:

```
  private async void AddReminder (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            var ReminderData = new Reminder
            {
                ReminderCreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                Status = false,
                ReminderLocation = locationentry.Text,
               ThingsTodo = new List<Tasks>(tasks)
            };


            if(tasks.Count <= 0 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(locationentry.Text))
            {
               await DisplayAlert("Hey boss!", "I need a location and at least a task to get this done", "ok");
            }
            else
            {
                await controller.AddReminder(ReminderData);

                DependencyService.Get<IToast>().ShowMessage("Reminder Created boss");
                locationentry.Text = "";
                tasks.Clear();
            }            

        }
```

This my controller for saving Reminder object:

```
 public async Task AddReminder(Reminder reminder)
        {

            await dbconnection.InsertAsync(reminder);                      
        }
```

I expect to be able to save a Reminder object alongside a list of Tasks and each of this tasks having same ReminderId so they can be retrieved as a part of the Reminder object. I dont know how i am supposed to save the Tasks and Reminder. Please help me inspect my code and tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to save list onject into Sqlite database, I suggest you can use **Text blobbed properties**, from [SQLite-Net Extensions library](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/).

```
 public class Reminder
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int ReminderId { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string ReminderLocation { get; set; }
    //in terms of days
    public DateTime ReminderCreationDate { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<Tasks> ThingsTodo { get; set; }
    [TextBlob(nameof(Taskblodded))]
    public string Taskblodded { get; set; }
}
```

> Text-blobbed properties are serialized into a text property when saved
>   and deserialized when loaded. This allows storing simple objects in
>   the same table in a single column.
>
> Text-blobbed properties have a small overhead of serializing and
>   deserializing the objects and some limitations, but are the best way
>   to store simple objects like List or Dictionary of basic types or
>   simple relationships. Text-blobbed properties require a declared
>   string property where the serialized object is stored.
>
> Text-blobbed properties cannot have relationships to other objects nor
>   inverse relationship to its parent.
>
> A JSON-based serializer is used if no other serializer has been
>   specified using TextBlobOperations.SetTextSerializer method. To use
>   the JSON serializer, a reference to Newtonsoft Json.Net library must
>   be included in the project, also available as a NuGet package.